# Flutter chat app, how to update username after user changes it in app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning flutter and currently im making chat app using Firebase.

I just added user functionality to change username.
Changing username works, in drawer I see new username immediately after change, also when I write new message its changing on FirebaseFirestore but on my chat its not changing and to be honest I have no idea how to change it, thats why I am looking for help.

This is file where I manage chat messages on my chat_screen:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final authenticatedUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('chat')
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
        if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        final loadedMessages = chatSnapshot.data!.docs;
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 40,
            left: 13,
            right: 13,
          ),
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: loadedMessages.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            final chatMessage = loadedMessages[index].data();
            final nextMessage = index + 1 < loadedMessages.length
                ? loadedMessages[index + 1].data()
                : null;
            final currentMessageUserId = chatMessage['userId'];
            final nextMessageUserId =
                nextMessage != null ? nextMessage['userId'] : null;
            final nextUserIsSame = currentMessageUserId == nextMessageUserId;

            if (nextUserIsSame) {
              return MessageBubble.next(
                message: chatMessage['text'],
                isMe: authenticatedUser.uid == currentMessageUserId,
              );
            } else {
              return MessageBubble.first(
                userImage: chatMessage['userImage'],
                username: chatMessage['username'],
                message: chatMessage['text'],
                isMe: authenticatedUser.uid == currentMessageUserId,
              );
            }
          },
        );
      });
  }
}
```

I thought of trying FutureBuilder, but I don't know how to implement this.